# Wordpress Plugin for private and possible mass messaging

Tags: wordpress

So Im creating an intranet site for the company I work for and we are implementing Buddypress. However we are turning off private messaging so low level access employees cannot message each other via Buddypress. Are there any recommendations for a plugin that will allow management to send mass messages to everybody based on user level.

For example, John Doe will be sick, Manager A sends 1 message to everybody in the company saying John Doe will not be in today but also sends a 2nd message to only management with user level management that John Doe is not coming in because they drank too much.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The problem. I need a plugin, what I've done so far to solve it, searched the Wordpress plugin library, as well as google.

Comment: This is a programming community. You're expected to ask questions about programming, not to ask for software recommendations. Please review [Stack Overflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this community works. Visiting the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) is also a good idea.

Comment: Can someone program me a plugin that will do those things I requested above?

Comment: Sure, but again this isn't the place for that kind of requests. Please go to a freelance jobs site (WordPress Jobs, Fiverr, Upwork, etc) and make your inquiry there.

Comment: You're right, that does seem like a lot of work. Maybe somebodies already coded one. Huh wonder where one might go to ask about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Front End PM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/) was perfect for this problem.